# Programmatically convert docx file to doc

Tags: c#, docx, doc

What options do I have to convert .docx documents to .doc document programmatically using C#? I'm looking to do this as cheaply as possible. Ideally I want to do this directly in code via libraries within the .net framework or via a well establish downloadable dll.

The one constraint we have is that we can't install Office onto our servers.

Comment: Can you Thinstall Office? Can you run it in a virtual Machine? You can then use an automator of some sort ...

Comment: Unfortunately we can't put office onto our servers via any means.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285700/programatically-convert-word-docx-to-doc-without-using-ole-automation

Answer (score 3):

Consider [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).  It is a high quality product that is fast, reasonably priced and accurate. Converting documents from docx to doc, even with Word automation may result in data loss and may impact fidelity. This may be very important to some users.

I'm not affiliated with their product.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Office` and `Office` assembly to convert the Docx file into Doc programmatically. It is part of Visual studio

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14"
```

I am not sure internally these dlls are take support from Office.
But you can try on this.Because I converted Doc to ppt file and it is working fine without Office installation on my Machine.

Comment: COM is good. It is even better when avoided though. This is a good solution if you need bare metal.

Comment: You have to have office installed to use Interop so this doesn't answer the question..