# Console application throw exception in application but not in debug

Tags: vb.net, console-application

Exception thrown every time in console application while running this simple code

```
    Public Function convertWord(ByVal file As String, ByVal Path As String) As Integer

    Dim convertObj As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

    Try
        convertObj = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
        WordDoc = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
        WordDoc = convertObj.Documents.Open(Path)
        WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(file, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF)
        Return 2
    Catch ex As Exception
        _checkLog("Originalna greška je : " & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace)
        Return 5
    End Try

End Function
```

If i use debug mode this function works perfect.  Otherwise

`Log check: 30.12.2015. 11:17:15 Originalna greška je : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line 34`

> Line 34>>>WordDoc = convertObj.Documents.Open(Path)

Comment: .Documents seems to be [Nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837437/interop-word-documents-open-is-null). _"The Document object is a member of the Documents collection. The Documents collection contains all the Document objects that are currently open in Microsoft Word."_. Are there any documents opened?
Additionally `_checkLog` `file` and `Path` params.

Comment: Hey sir i think that might be a problem. My file and path params are good 
`Log check: 30.12.2015. 13:19:12 File je : G:\POSLOVNO\menzur\635870783515338248.pdf
Log check: 30.12.2015. 13:19:12 Path je : G:\POSLOVNO\menzur\635870783515338248.docx
Log check: 30.12.2015. 13:19:13 Originalna greška je : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at OfficeConvert.convertWord(String file, String Path) in C:\Users\Desktop\servis\OfficeConvert.vb:line 37`

Comment: But when i try to convert Excell i got this error `Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '...0680735.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter,.....`

Comment: New research i put _log on file before proceed. The function returns True if the file is open. The results :(
`Log check: 30.12.2015. 13:34:25 File open : False` which means file is not opened for sure.

Comment: Have you tried the first answer of my SO link I posted?

Comment: Alex B. that solved my problem thanks a lot. 
Post it as answer so i can click solved. 

I will give my best and try to find simplier solution . Maybe to set this `Identity` through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open DCOM Config Settings:

```
1. Start -> dcomcnfg.exe
2. Computer
3. Local Computer
4. Config DCOM
5. Search for Microsoft Word 97-2003 Documents -> Properties
```

Tab Identity, change from Launching User to Interactive User.

Comment: On the similar way i fixed the excell problem. Thanks sir