# Can I save a DOCX file as HTML using the DOCX Library?

Tags: c#, html, docx, file-conversion, novacode-docx

I am using the DOCX library to manipulate *.docx files.

I would like to save a *docx file as an html file, but this code:

```
using (DocX sourceDoc = DocX.Create(sourceFilename))
{
    sourceDoc.SaveAs(sourceHTMLFileName); 
}
```

...does not work (sourceHTMLFileName is "Bla.html").

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of DocX has stated in a [blog post](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html) that his library does not support this feature yet. I got the link from the [codeplex page](https://docx.codeplex.com/) for the library.)

Quote from the link:

> I would love to add this functionality to DocX, however there is a problem.
>
> [...]
>
> The only easy way to do this conversion, is to use Microsoft’s Office interop libraries
>
> [...]
>
> Is there no way to do conversions without having Word.exe installed on my machine. I didn’t say that, I said there is no easy way. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285700/programatically-convert-word-docx-to-doc-without-using-ole-automation) looks very promising, now if I could only find the time.

He suggests a workaround using Interop but that might not be possible depending on your environment.

Using `SaveAs` with a file that ends in `.html` simply saves a `.docx` file with the wrong extension; there is no conversion done.

Comment: "Using SaveAs with a file that ends in .html simply saves a .docx file with the wrong extension; there is no conversion done."
Yes, I noticed.

Comment: I think you have to use your own implementation to read data from the word and convert to html.
`MagicText` has `FormattedText` property where you can get style information for text but you cannot get the positions.

Better to use `OpenXml` libraries and use `HtmlConverter` class